# XSP.getElementById vs document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, xpages

What is the difference between `XSP.getElementById` and `document.getElementById`? In my tests both seem to return the same value (value stored in field). Which one should be preferred while coding for XPages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**edited**

`XSP.getElementById` is the same as `dojo.byId` which I believe works in wider range of browsers than `document.getElementById`.

Here is the source for `XSP.getElementById`:

```
   /**
    * Convenience function for retrieving an element given its id in a browser independent manner.
    */
    this.getElementById = function x_gbi(elementId){
        return dojo.byId(elementId);
    }
```

I guess for better future XPage support it might be a good idea to use `XSP.getElementById` (because they might change it) instead of `dojo.byId`. I've been using `dojo.byId` because it's shorter. `document.getElementById` should never be used in XPages because we have `dojo.byId`.

**update**

Starting from Dojo 1.7 the syntax is much more complex:

```
require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){
    // fetch a node by id="someNode"
    var node = dom.byId("someNode");
});
```

Today my colleque pointed out that *Dojo 2* will not support the current simple way of calling `dojo.byId` any more. This means that `XSP.getElementById` is definitely the way to go and we should start using the new `require` based syntax whenever we use Dojo with ND9.

Comment: I am sorry I am a bit confused here. How does this answer my question!

Comment: @Naveen I added some info about the difference.

Comment: @Naveen Sorry I read the compressed JS incorrectly. Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 3):

XSP contains code for handling situations with the Notes client (XPiNC) and the web browser. Not using XSP calls in XPiNC may work or may have side effects.

XSP.getElementById works the same way as document.getElementById except it ensures that it works across browsers with the same functionality.

You can read more about how XSP works in the "XPages Portable Command Guide" Page 184 for getElementById.